# Progressive image in Picasso - android

Tags: android, picasso, android-vectordrawable

I am using from `Picasso` for show image in my app .I set a default image for `Picasso` that it is `vector`. Like bellow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp">
    <path
        android:pathData="M0 0L24 0 24 24 0 24Z"
        android:fillColor="#dcdcdc" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M15.9 15.9l-7.8 0c-0.5 0 -1 -0.4 -1 -1L7.1 9c0 -0.5 0.4 -1 1 -1L16 8c0.5 0 1 0.4 1 1l0 6c-0.1 0.5 -0.5 0.9 -1.1 0.9zm0 -6.9l-7.8 0 0 6 7.9 0 0 -6zm-3.9 3.5l1 -0.5 2 1.2 0 0.8 -6 0 0 -2 1 -1 2 1.5zm2.2 -1c-0.4 0 -0.7 -0.3 -0.7 -0.7 0 -0.4 0.3 -0.7 0.7 -0.7 0.4 0 0.7 0.3 0.7 0.7 0 0.4 -0.3 0.7 -0.7 0.7z"
        android:fillColor="#ffffff" />
</vector>
```

And I use from it in `Picasso` :

```
    Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
            .load(productsModelList.getPictureUrl())
.placeholder(AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(context, R.drawable.placeholder_pictures))
            .fit()
            .into(imgImageProduct);
```

**Problem** : When I use from default image(**vector**) in `Picasso` when I get image `url` from server and load the Image it is Progressive(Obscure) but when I use from default image(**jpg**) everything works fine .

But when I use from **jpg** everything works fine :

```
        Picasso.with(itemView.getContext())
                .load(productsModelList.getPictureUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_picture)
                .fit()
                .into(imgImageProduct);
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my problem. I changed size of `vector` `android:width="150dp"` and `android:height="150dp"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:width="150dp"
    android:height="150dp">
    <path
        android:pathData="M0 0L24 0 24 24 0 24Z"
        android:fillColor="#dcdcdc" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M15.9 15.9l-7.8 0c-0.5 0 -1 -0.4 -1 -1L7.1 9c0 -0.5 0.4 -1 1 -1L16 8c0.5 0 1 0.4 1 1l0 6c-0.1 0.5 -0.5 0.9 -1.1 0.9zm0 -6.9l-7.8 0 0 6 7.9 0 0 -6zm-3.9 3.5l1 -0.5 2 1.2 0 0.8 -6 0 0 -2 1 -1 2 1.5zm2.2 -1c-0.4 0 -0.7 -0.3 -0.7 -0.7 0 -0.4 0.3 -0.7 0.7 -0.7 0.4 0 0.7 0.3 0.7 0.7 0 0.4 -0.3 0.7 -0.7 0.7z"
        android:fillColor="#ffffff" />
</vector>
```